# Is there a way to implement native ipad/iphone 'flipping' through an album of pictures through a website?

Tags: ipad

I think I've seen some implementations in flash, although I'm not sure.

On my ipad, through the photos app, you can open an album and scan through FULLSCREEN images using the flick to move it from side to side. My question is: can this be implemented through a website flipping through a album (collection of images)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that might help:

http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/PzQgs/

It doesn't handle the mouse gestures, but shows one way to 'flip' full screen images.

To handle the 'flick' mouse gesture, you'd need to track mouse position and button states with event handlers & timers.

Comment: This does the job. Thank you and Omnipotent.

Answer (score 0):

The "flipping" mechanism you're describing is called "cover flow"  And there's a few implementations on the internets.  The one I've heard recommended the most is http://xflow.pwhitrow.com/

Comment: I don't think I'm talking about cover flow. I'm talking about simply using the 'flick' gesture to slide to the next image. No actual picture flipping.